# Override Firefox element.style display

Tags: css

This [site](http://www.victoriagray.co.uk/writing) produces an unwanted display in Firefox but fine everywhere else, i've narrowed it down to the display: block - in the element.style for the  DIV Slides_Container, but can't seem to edit it no matter how hard I try. Any ideas would be great! Cheers.

Comment: You'll have to use an `!important` rule to override the inline style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you didn't include any code. Which is very naughty:

```
.slides_container {
    display: inline-block !important;
}
```

Is what you'll be wanting to add!

Comment: No problem, you're more likely to get responses if you include code for people to get their dirty little mitts on!! :) Don't forget to accept the answer ;)